# What class of histone deacetylase (HDAC) inhibitor is sodium valproate (VPA)?

Tags: histone-deacetylase

VPA is a known HDAC inhibitor. But I cannot find what class it is.

What class is it?

And is there any method of finding an answer better than floundering with Google?

Answer (score 2):

This is explained at [the WP page for HDAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histone_deacetylase_inhibitor#HDAC_classification). There are five classes:

> hydroxamic acids (or hydroxamates), such as trichostatin A
>
> cyclic tetrapeptides (such as trapoxin B), and the depsipeptides
>
> benzamides
>
> electrophilic ketones
>
> the aliphatic acid compounds such as phenylbutyrate and valproic acid

and valproate is in the final class, aliphatic acids.